# How to delete an element from a slice that's inside a map?

Tags: go

I have a a map which has a key and multiple values for that key.

What i want to do is delete a single value from values.

Example:

```golang
map1 := make(map[string][]string)
str1 := []string{"Jon", "Doe", "Captain", "America"}
str2 := "Doe"
map1["p1"] = str1
```

In the above example I want to remove value form the "p1" if it is present in str2, in my case it is "Doe"

after removing the value map should be like this
`p1:[Jon Captain America]`

Is this possible or do i have to rewrite the whole map again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to *"in place"* delete an element from a slice that's inside a map. You need to first get the slice from the map, delete the element from the slice, and then store the result of that in the map.

For finding the element's index by its value and then deleting it from the slice you can use the `golang.org/x/exp/slices` package if you are using Go1.18.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/exp/slices"
)

func main() {
    map1 := make(map[string][]string)
    str1 := []string{"Jon", "Doe", "Captain", "America"}
    str2 := "Doe"
    map1["p1"] = str1

    idx := slices.Index(map1["p1"], str2)
    map1["p1"] = slices.Delete(map1["p1"], idx, idx+1)

    fmt.Println(map1)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/EDTGAJT-VdM

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

func main () {
    var sessions = map[string] chan int{};
    delete(sessions, "moo");
}
```

or

```
package main

func main () {
    var sessions = map[string] chan int{};
    sessions["moo"] = make (chan int);
    _, ok := sessions["moo"];
    if ok {
        delete(sessions, "moo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Directly from the Bible of Golang: Effective Go:  
"To delete a map entry, use the delete built-in function, whose arguments are the map and the key to be deleted. It's safe to do this even if the key is already absent from the map."

Comment: Given the map `map[p1:[Jon Doe Captain America]]`, the key `"p1"`, and the value `"Doe"` how exactly is the code in your answer supposed to produce the desired result of `map[p1:[Jon Captain America]]`? Admittedly the title of the question is misleading, but if you read the body of the question you'll see that your answer is not helpful in any way.